# Edit comments don't update

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list

1. Find a post that needs editing.
2. Edit the post and save your edits.
3. Realize you forgot to describe the changes in the edit comments box.  It just says something like "replaced xxx characters in body" or "edited tags", etc.
4. Go back to edit and describe your actual changes better and save.
5. The edit history is not updated with the revised comment!

Comment: When you edited the second time, was all that changed the edit summary? I think that ends up being a no-op, although I suppose it wouldn't hurt to take the edit summary into account and update it if you were still in the grace period.

Comment: I've seen it both ways.  Either editing the body, or just the summary, it doesn't seem to take the new summary into account while it's in the grace period.  If I wait long enough, and then make an edit to the body *and* the summary, then it takes.

Comment: Noticed this some time ago, didn't see it as significant enough to post a Meta discussion. My workaround - just add like a blank line at the end or something doesn't change the output.